# Trying to draw full-width rectangles but there are white spaces at the image's borders, why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library, dpi

## Summary

- Context
- Actual results (the problem revealed)
- Expected results (if the problem is solved)
- Clues to help you to help me
- Minimal and Testable Executable Code

  - Prerequisites
  - Sources

---

## Context

I want to draw full-width colored rectangle in a 515x515 image. What I get is:

[image]

## Actual results (the problem revealed)

If you open it in Paint, you will see that the right and bottom borders of the image contain white pixels. It means that in fact, my rectangles are not full-width. Moreover, top and left borders contain colors different than the rectangles' ones. Also, the color between two consecutive rectangles is differerent than the rectangles' colors.

## Expected results (if the problem is solved)

What I would want is: to make the image contain only the colors of the rectangles (1 rectangle = 1 color of course), and no other color ; to know why there are white pixels ; to know why there are colors that are different than the rectangles' ones between two consecutive rectangles. And, of course: how to replace any color that is not a rectangle's one by the correct rectangle's one?

## Clues to help you to help me

In my other computer, I don't have these problems. Perhaps the issue is bound to the way I use DPI unit, in the call to my function `open_eps`? See the following code.

## Minimal and Testable Executable Code

### Prerequisites

1. To reproduce this bug, you can, normally (it seems to depend on your computer and/or screen I don't know), execute the above code in your Python interpreter. No input data is required for the execution, you can launch the script alone. It should be easy to reproduce the bug I think (tell me if it's not the case).
2. Python Interpreter: you can use 3.7 as I do but I think it's not required ; By the way, I'm on Windows so you can change files paths if you use UNIX or some other reasons.

### Sources

Here is the code that generates these images ; just execute this code (there is randomness, at each execution a different image could be drawn ; the bug will be always present):

```
 import io    
 import math
 import random
 from tkinter import Canvas, Tk
    
 import PIL.Image
    
def open_eps(ps, dpi=300.0):
    img = PIL.Image.open(io.BytesIO(ps.encode('utf-8')))
    original = [float(d) for d in img.size]
    scale = dpi / 72.0
    if dpi is not 0:
        img.load(scale=math.ceil(scale))
    if scale != 1:
        img.thumbnail([round(scale * d) for d in original])
    return img

def generate_terrain():
        canvas_width = 512
        canvas_height = 512
        root = Tk()
        canvas = Canvas(root, width=canvas_width, height=canvas_height)
        canvas.pack()
        canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, canvas_width, canvas_height / 3, fill='#9ceedd', outline='#9ceedd', width=3)
        clouds = random.randint(0, 1)
        layout = 0
        ground = random.randint(0, 1)
        plants = random.randint(0, 2)
        if layout == 0:
            if clouds == 0:
                canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, canvas_width, 50, fill='#696969', outline='#696969', width=3)
            if ground == 0:
                ground = '#6e6e28'
            if ground == 1:
                ground = '#999900'
            canvas.create_rectangle(0, 2 * (canvas_height / 3), canvas_width, canvas_height, fill=ground,
                                    outline=ground, width=3)
            if plants == 0:
                plants = '#7bc800'
            if plants == 1:
                plants = '#760000'
            if plants == 2:
                plants = '#a8c832'
            canvas.create_rectangle(0, (canvas_height / 3), canvas_width, 2 * (canvas_height / 3), fill=plants,
                                    outline=plants, width=3)
        canvas.update()
        ps = canvas.postscript()
        root.destroy()
        img = open_eps(ps, dpi=95.5)
        img.save("C:/Users/x/Desktop/a/b/test.png")

generate_terrain()
```

Answer (score 0):

Well. I tried another way to save the image (a workaround) and now it works. However you can still answer this question, of course.

I have replaced `width=6` with: `width=3`.

I have replaced `img = open_eps(ps, dpi=95.5)` with: `img = PIL.Image.open(io.BytesIO(ps.encode('utf-8')))`.